# Ubuntu server keeps running out of memory

Tags: ubuntu, memory, ubuntu-11.04

I have a VPS running Ubuntu 11.04 server, every week or so I have to reboot it as (I think) it's run out of memory.

It has 256MB of RAM available and I've tried configuring Apache to run less RAM-heavy but to no avail.

Can you advise what my next course of action should be? I'm guessing there's a log somewhere that'll tell me what happened and when, where can I find that?

---

**Edit:**

I think it's running out of memory because I remember seeing error messages when I log in via my serial console (when it crashes I can't SSH, etc). I can't remember the messages exactly but it said something about unable to create apache process - kill PID something or other (sorry to be so vague!).

Here's the output from `top`...

```
top - 09:42:40 up 16:10,  1 user,  load average: 0.01, 0.11, 0.12
Tasks:  78 total,   1 running,  77 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  0.2%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni, 99.8%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:    244284k total,   230528k used,    13756k free,     3348k buffers
Swap:   262140k total,   191868k used,    70272k free,    63008k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
 1079 www-data  20   0  322m  26m  276 S  0.0 11.1   0:02.78 apache2
 1072 www-data  20   0  260m  26m  192 S  0.0 10.9   0:02.49 apache2
  877 www-data  20   0  255m  25m  140 S  0.0 10.6   0:02.89 apache2
  872 www-data  20   0  249m  22m  200 S  0.0  9.6   0:02.93 apache2
  875 www-data  20   0  263m  10m  132 S  0.0  4.4   0:03.53 apache2
 1141 www-data  20   0  267m 9.8m  172 S  0.0  4.1   0:02.81 apache2
  451 mysql     20   0  241m 2296   68 S  0.0  0.9   0:21.08 mysqld
  923 www-data  20   0  263m 2188   44 S  0.0  0.9   0:03.10 apache2
 1865 root      20   0 18232 2088 1380 S  0.0  0.9   0:00.05 bash
  924 www-data  20   0  252m 2012  256 S  0.0  0.8   0:02.90 apache2
 1852 root      20   0 93524 1940  980 S  0.0  0.8   0:00.11 sshd
 1077 www-data  20   0  252m 1824  128 S  0.0  0.7   0:01.58 apache2
 1171 www-data  20   0  228m 1640  216 S  0.0  0.7   0:01.68 apache2
  833 root      20   0  207m 1432  268 S  0.0  0.6   0:02.19 apache2
 2053 root      20   0 19352 1268  948 R  0.3  0.5   0:00.02 top
 1805 postfix   20   0 39428 1160  708 S  0.0  0.5   0:00.01 pickup
    1 root      20   0 23980  808  304 S  0.0  0.3   0:00.27 init
  397 syslog    20   0 54452  600  460 S  0.0  0.2   0:00.27 rsyslogd
  390 root      20   0 49464  436  260 S  0.0  0.2   0:00.01 sshd
  934 postfix   20   0 41944  380  232 S  0.0  0.2   0:00.05 tlsmgr
  638 root      20   0 37364  372  272 S  0.0  0.2   0:00.22 master
  801 proftpd   20   0 98.5m  328  228 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.38 proftpd
  646 postfix   20   0 39592  300  236 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.06 qmgr
  437 root      20   0 18928  280  196 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.16 cron
  244 root      18  -2 21268  152  148 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 udevd
  421 root      20   0  6196  136  132 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 getty
  422 root      20   0  6196  136  132 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 getty
  426 root      20   0  6196  136  132 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 getty
  428 root      20   0  6196  136  132 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 getty
  431 root      20   0  6196  136  132 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 getty
  864 root      20   0  6196  136  132 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 getty
  866 root      20   0  6196  136  132 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 getty
  198 root      16  -4 21280  124  120 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.03 udevd
  246 root      18  -2 21144  116  112 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 udevd
  541 memcache  20   0 63008   80   80 S  0.0  0.0   0:02.08 memcached
  727 root      20   0 54764   80   76 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 saslauthd
  438 daemon    20   0 16728   64   64 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 atd
  316 root      20   0 15004    4    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.01 upstart-socket-
  728 root      20   0 54764    4    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 saslauthd
  729 root      20   0 54764    4    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 saslauthd
  730 root      20   0 54764    4    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 saslauthd
  731 root      20   0 54764    4    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 saslauthd
    2 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kthreadd
    3 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.76 ksoftirqd/0
    4 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:01.24 kworker/0:0
    5 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.16 kworker/u:0
    6 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 migration/0
    7 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 cpuset
    8 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 khelper
    9 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 netns
   10 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 xenwatch
   11 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 xenbus
   12 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.07 sync_supers
```

The server is running fine at the minute - I only know something has happened when I can't access FTP or MySQL.

Comment: Why do you think it's run out of memory? What's the symptom?

Answer (score 0):

Well it depends on what type of sites you are running on your Apache. I have had websites with picture galleries on them crash with 512 MB of memory. You should do a test, setup a similar setup, install a graphing tool like munin, and start visiting your website. You can see where you generate load.

If it's not that, but you see a graph that keeps growing up exponentially, you might have a memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

If you've run out of memory, you will see OOM killer messages in /var/log/messages.  Check that log after an incident.

As to what's using up memory, that's hard to say without more details on your setup.  You can always run, say, `top` and sort by mem usage to have a quick look at what's going on.

Comment: Looking at your updated post: get a bigger service tier for your VPS.  You can try to reduce the number of Apache workers, also, but I don't think it'll make a big enough difference over the long haul.